# Validate json to determine under-post in NJsonSchema C#

Tags: c#, json, njsonschema

Given a json schema built by swagger I'd like to validate a json requests and responses of my endpoints. If my json data has not all non-required fields, that are described in the schema, then no errors are returned. How can I modify/extend behavior to determine the absence of that fields?

I disassembled the schema and validator code and didn't found an easy way to override the behavior of the schema and of the validator.

`var wholeSchema = JsonSchema.FromFileAsync("mypath\\myJson.json").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var specificRequestSchema = wholeSchema.Definitions["specificRequest"];
    var errors = specificRequestSchema.Validate(jsonData);`

Comment: If its a swagger spec you need to read it with OpenApiDocument.ReadFileAsync and the validate using the request schema etc

Comment: Nswag does not provide this out of the box abd the validator is for json schema but not for openapi (might be differen)